# If $\alpha_n\to 0$, $x_n=O(\alpha_n)$, and $y_n=O(\alpha_n)$, then $x_ny_n=o(\alpha_n)$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, numerical-methods, asymptotics

If $\alpha_n\to 0$, $x_n=O(\alpha_n)$, and $y_n=O(\alpha_n)$, then $x_ny_n=o(\alpha_n)$.

I know that $x_n=O(\alpha_n)$ means there exists a constant $C$ and integer $n_0$ such that $|x_n|\leq C|\alpha_n|$ for all $n\geq n_0$. Any solutions or hints are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try to prove this by definition. You already wrote definition of $O$, write that of $o$ and see why does it hold.

Comment: For little oh I need to find a positive sequence that converges to zero.

Comment: Huh, let me guess. $C|\alpha_n|$?

Comment: It's as simple as using one of the $\alpha_n$ sequences?

Comment: I told you it's by definition. So it's simple, yes.

Answer (score 2):

By assumption there are $M_{1},M_{2} \geq 0$ such that $|x_{n}| \leq M_{1}|\alpha_{n}|$ and $|y_{n}| \leq M_{2}|\alpha_{n}|$ for large $n$, so $|x_{n}y_{n}| \leq M_{1}M_{2}|\alpha_{n}|^{2}$ for large $n$. Since $\alpha_{n} = o(1)$ by assumption, we are done.

Comment: So you choose the sequence to be $\alpha_n$?

Comment: By definition $x_{n} = O(a_{n})$ means that there is some $M \geq 0$ such that $|x_{n}| \leq M|a_{n}|$ for large $n$. No matter what definition you are using, it must be equivalent to this one.

Comment: Moreover, $\alpha_{n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ is equivalent to $\alpha_{n} = o(1)$.as $n \to \infty$.